Connect-ExchangeOnline hangs/freezes when using Powershell 7
And yet it works perfectly when using Powershell version 5.  I am using ExchangeOnlineManagement v 3.5.0 in both Powershell prompts.  I also included the -Verbose parameter, but this is all the it shows:
VERBOSE: Returning precomputed version info: 3.5.0
VERBOSE: ModuleVersion: 3.5.0

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module without any change.  Any advice would be appreciated.
Edit:
This command is normally used in a script,
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Read-Host "Please enter your *FULL* AZ admin email"  $Email 
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $Email 
...

Based on other people's posts I tried running it in a regular powershell session.  I just enter the same statements that are in the script.  But both end up just hanging.
Here is what I see when I terminate command
Error Acquiring Token:
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.InterceptAuthorizationUriAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, Boolean isBrokerConfigured, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync(IWebUI webUi, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenInteractiveParameters interactiveParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.AdminApiProvider.Authentication.MSALTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(String claims, String cmdletId)


So you run just the command Connect-ExchangeOnline without any parameters, correct? You should list this in your post, the actual command(s) you're running. Then, you should add details about where/how it hangs. Does it load an external window? Hint: in 5.1 it should, in 7+ it may open a new tab in your browser.

I just updated it.  I even tried using a earlier version of the module.  Still no progress.  It does open as you mentioned.  After trying again I noticed that running PS 7 as admin allows the command to work (including opening a new tab), but I need to run this on a script as a different user (AD admin).  I don't know why the difference in user would matter if they have the same version of the module installed.

Also this command was usable in powershell 5 when running it as the AD admin account.

To me, it's unlikely it's "hanging" but instead has opened in a browser tab/window that you aren't seeing. None-the-less, if you use the parameter -Device that will allow you to manually go get connected.
First, run your same command with the suggested parameter.
Read-Host "Please enter your *FULL* AZ admin email"  $Email 
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $Email -Device

You will see a message like this

Navigate to the listed url in your preferred browser on a device of your choosing. Enter the code and complete the Exchange Online/365 login. Once complete, the browser should indicate success

At the same time the command should complete authentication and return


That definitely helps, I just wish it would spawn a window to authenticate like on powershell 5, is that even possible?  If not then I may be able to make that work.  Now I just need to deal with the conflict between MS Graph and ExchangeOnlineManagement or Pnp.poweshell modules.  Thanks!

I find it hard to believe it's not. Have you ensured all your browsers are all closed? Maybe you have something in your environment blocking it such as Antivirus or threatlocker or you could simply be missing the window/tab it's opening.
